# Bounds in a triple integral

Tags: integration

I have been asked to evaluate this triple integral, but the bounds dont make much sense to me. How can i get started on this one?

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{1+y}^{2y}\int_{z}^{z+y} z \mathrm dx\mathrm dy\mathrm dz$$

Thanks in advance

Bjarne

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$...=\int_0^1\mathrm dy\int_{1+y}^{2y}z\mathrm dz\int_z^{z+y}\mathrm  dx=\int_0^1\mathrm dy\int_{1+y}^{2y}zy\mathrm dz=\int_0^1y\mathrm dy\int_{1+y}^{2y}zdz=\int_0^1y\mathrm dy\left[\frac{4y^2}{2}-\frac{(1+y)^2}{2}\right]=...$$